# How can I read data from MySQL database into a process in jBPM Web Designer?

Tags: mysql, database, jbpm

In the default "evaluation" example in jBPM 5.4, I want to replace the actors "john" and "mary" with actors defined in a file or in a database, if possible, through the jbpm web designer. How can I do that? I have searched the web and the forums and I found no solution for this.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I have installed MySQl and created and populated a table. I now want to assign variables values from this table. I have no idea how that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate mysql with jbpm5 as shown [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SetUpJBPM54FinalInstallerToUseMySQL-OrHowToRunSection37OfTheUserGuide#Set_up_MySQL)

 Also you can write java handlers to fetch data from files or databases and then use #{expression} to assign actor id dynamically.
Comment if anything is not clear.

Comment: What is java handler and how to attach them to the process? How to map #{expression} to handler name? Is there a tutorial for this? Any help would be appreciated.