# How to read and save to database from JBPM process?

Tags: jboss, jbpm, business-process-management

I would like to make a jBPM process that reads data from external database at the beginning, do some processing and at the end saves results to the same external database. Is it possible? How?

I've tried with Data Sets but I don't know how to use it in my process.

I've read this thread: [How can I read data from MySQL database into a process in jBPM Web Designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273137/how-can-i-read-data-from-mysql-database-into-a-process-in-jbpm-web-designer) but I don't know how to "write java handlers".

Answer (score 0):

You can either write your own [WorkItemHandler](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.4.0.Final/kie-api-javadoc/org/kie/api/runtime/process/WorkItemHandler.html) implementation which will retrieve and store the data in the database or you can reuse existing [JPAWorkItemHandler](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-workitems/src/main/java/org/jbpm/process/workitem/jpa/JPAWorkItemHandler.java). Then you will just need to add a task (served by your work item handler) to your process definition. You will find more information how to implement and register custom work item handlers in the [jBPM documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/6.4.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html/ch21.html).